# Is there a more elegant way to write this getter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

New to Kotlin - curious if there is a more elegant way to write the `duration` getter for the following class (or any other style tips or gotchas):

```
open class Timeline(
    open var props: MutableList<Prop> = mutableListOf()) {

    val duration: Long
        get() {
            var best: Prop? = null
            props.forEach {
                if (best == null || it.interval.end > best?.interval!!.end) {
                    best = it
                }
            }
            return best?.interval?.end ?: 0L
        }
}
```

Essentially it's just finding the prop with the greatest interval.  I am aware that I could just ensure that the `props` `List` is sorted when adding items to it and simply grab the item at the end of the list, but that's not the question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - like this? val duration: `Long  get() = props.map { it.interval.end }.reduce { acc, l -> if (l > acc) l else acc }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to find the highest value of `end`, you can do this in a one-liner:

```
val duration: Long = 
    props.map { it.interval.end }.max() ?: 0L
```

Essentially this says: "Convert every `Prop` to its `interval.end` value and take the max value. If there is no max value, return 0".

To expand on this, if you wanted the `Prop` with the highest `interval.end`, you would write it this way:

```
val bestProp: Prop? = 
    props.maxBy { it.interval.end }
```

Which means: "Find the `Prop` with the max `interval.end`, or null if none is found".

Comment: Thanks, i like this

Comment: Might just be an overlook, but Your answer is functionally different than OPs code: it's property initialization instead of a getter that might return different values as `props` change.

Comment: A very valid point, @Pawel. A small change is all that would be needed.

`get() = props.map { it.interval.end }.max() ?: 0L`